# Add html file in content repository hugo and link it to scss

Tags: html, sass, markdown, hugo

This is the tree of my hugo website:

```
.
├── archetypes
├── assets
├── config.toml
├── content
├── layouts
├── Makefile
├── node_modules
├── package.json
├── public
├── README.md
├── resources
├── static
└── www.deploy
```

I would like to know if it is possible to add /page2/index.html in the repository /content, so having /content/page2/index.html.
Usually there are only markdown files in the repository /content.
I am pretty sure it is possible in some way.

If it is possible to have a html file in /content, how can I link it to a scss file? The scss file will be store in the repository /assets/scss/pages2/pages.scss.

If it is not possible to add the html file in /content, so how can I do to add a new page in hugo? Add a html file in /layout folder: /layout/page2/index.html linked to /content/page2/index.md?

I am very confused.

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing to me. Would you like to describe what you are trying to achieve, instead of how you think it could/should be done? E.g., do you want a "static" page that is not a post, and with a layout different than the rest of your pages?

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I want! It is a new page, not a blog, that is different than the other pages so I can't use shortcodes.

Answer (score 1):

Files in `content/` are source files: files written in markdown, org-mode, etc. which will be rendered by the site into html. So this is not the place where you would put an html file.

From the comments below your question, it sounds that what you are trying to achieve is to create a page that is different from the pages that your site normally renders.

The way to go about this is to edit the layouts. I would need more information about your site to answer with concrete information. But things will end up looking something like this:

```
content/
  dir1/
    file1.md
    file2.md
    ...
  dir2/
    that-very-different-file.md
```

And in layouts, you will have to create a new layout for your very different looking page. So your layouts directory will look something like this:

```
layouts/
  dir1/
    single.html
  dir2/
    single.html
```

The `single.html` file in `dir1` contains the template layout for your regular files and the `single.html` in `dir2` the template for your very different page.